# searching letters in one line using grep and wc

Tags: grep, wc

I've created a text file with 1000 random uppercase and lowercase letters:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 1000 > file1
```

How many times does the word 'cat' appear in this file, using `grep` and `wc`?

I did it this way:

```
grep -ic cat file1
```

But it counts lines in which it appears, while I want to check how many times it appears in that one line. Any idea?

Comment: fyi, tr can use [:alnum:] instead of the a-z... And you want to count how many times it appears in the whole file, not just on ***each*** line , or in just one particular line (you said "in that one line" at the end)?

Answer (score 4):

> Work I have to do is find how many times in this file, appears world
>   'cat' using command `grep` and `wc`.

Try:

```
grep -oi cat file1 | wc -l
```

Example:

```
$ cat file1 
foo cat bar zoo cat
random text cat dog
foobar cat
end!
```

^We have four occurances of `cat` above.

```
grep -oi cat file1 | wc -l
4
```

---

From `man grep` (my emphasis):

```
       -o, --only-matching
              Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
              with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: The command above will find all substring *cat* even if they are part of other word like bob*cat* and *cat*alougue. But the file is created so that it contains no space, nither word brake nither line break. Hence this is just a note.

Comment: @schweik Yes, that is true. I did not add any word boundaries to my answer.